# Problem uninstalling SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had problems with SQL Server and i uninstalled/reinstalled a lot of things and tools of it. Now, SQL Server works, but the Management studio doesnt.

When i execute it i have the follow error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". And i cant do any query...

I tried to remove it and reinstall, but in the installation center i cant check management tools to remove it... it appear disabled. I cant uninstall it and also i cant reinstall it.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution: if you use SQL Server 2008, install SQL Server 2008 R2 side-by-side and use ssms from it.

Comment: Then try installing Denali http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/future-editions.aspx or, if possible, SQL Server 2008. I've had some experience with corrupted SQL Server installations, lost a lot of time but with no luck. Reinstall Windows or use other version — the only working solutions I've found.

Comment: It's imposible to install SQL Server 2008. All of the components are corrupted. I'm going to try Denali. It's the new version of SQL Server isn't it? It have SQL Management tool (I only need that)?

Comment: Yes, Denali is next SQL Server version. Haven't tried it actually myself, so I can't say for sure, but seems like 'SQL Management tool' can be next SSMS name.